# How to fix Ventura bug that ask for permissions already granted

Tags: permission, ventura

After update to Ventura there are some apps that asks for permissions that already granted on start up. I have to revoke the access and grant the permission again.
Is this a Ventura bug? Somebody know how to fix it?

Comment: Which version of Ventura? Bugs in 13..0.1 may have been fixed in 13.1

Comment: I had that hope but I'm using 13.1